# Scala: For comprehension with multiple conditions

Tags: scala

I have two lists, `val aList = List(2,3,5,15,20)` and `val bList = List (3,5,6)`.

What I need:
If an element in `aList` is *greater than 10*, then include the element in the result.
Else, if it is present in `bList`, then include the *square of the element*.
So, the answer for the above example would be `List(15,20,9,25)`. The result list can be in any order.

Is for-comprehension the most efficient way to do this? Is it possible to accomplish this in a single for-comprehension-yield?

Comment: Define efficient ?

Comment: Three of the four answers so far give a result different from the one in the question. But your description and answer don't really fit together. The answer seems to be "each numbers in aList > 10, then concatenate the qquare of each number <= 10 and in bList". Which doesn't really fit with your element-by-element description

Comment: I've updated the elements in bList. The result is still the same - hope it's clear

Comment: No, it's still not clear. You don't state that all the elements > 10 must come first in the answer *followed* by the square of each of the elements less or equal to 10 and in blist. If that's what you mean, you should say so. If it's OK to have the elements or their square in their original order, you should change your example output. But right now, your description says one thing and the example output another

Comment: Ordering is not an issue - I've updated the question for clarity.

Comment: OK, now it's clear. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
aList.flatMap { a =>
  if (a > 10) Option(a) else bList.find(_ == a).map(a => a * a)
}
```

We avoid unnecessary traversing `bList`.

Comment: If `bList` is large enough, I'd additionally add that a `Set[Int]` instead of a `List[Int]` might be preferable.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it in a single traversal, and for that you don't need a `for yield`, that's a `flatMap` syntax sugar, but you're not flat mapping anything in here.

```
val res = aList.foldLeft(List.empty[Int]) { (acc, el) =>
  if (el > 10) {
    el :: acc
  } else if (bList.contains(el)) {
    (el * el) :: acc
  } else {
    acc
  }
}
```

If you want to make this slightly prettier, subject to preference, as some people may not choose to write if statements using case matches religiously:

```
val res = aList.foldLeft(List.empty[Int]) { (acc, el) => el match {
    case e if e > 10 => el :: acc
    case e if bList.contains(e) => (e * e) :: acc
    case _ => acc
  }
}
```

The Big O for this would be `O(nlogm)`, where `n` is the size of `aList` and `m` the size of `bList`. In practice it's a little better, because you avoid a logarithmic time lookup for every element that's greater than 10. Unless my morning coffee has yet to take affect and I'm missing things.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like,

```
aList.filter(_>10) ++ bList.filter(aList.contains(_)).map(x => x*x)
```

Or to avoid greater than 10 elements from bList (if any),

```
aList.filter(_>10) ++ bList.filter(i => i<=10 && aList.contains(i)).map(x => x*x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any need of `for-comprehension` here. Also there is no simple way of using `for-compreshension` to accomplish this.

```
val aList = List(2,3,5,15,20)
val bList = List(3,5)
```

You can do it simply as (the conversion to Set will not guaruntee the oder preservation and may result in arbitrary order),

```
val commonEligibleInts = (aList.filter(i => i <= 10).toSet & bList.toSet).toList

val result = aList.filter(i => i > 10) ++ commonEligibleInts.map(i => i * i)

// result: List[Int] = List(15, 20, 9, 25)
```

You can use `for-comprehension` like following but that will not give you the required ordering (the order here will be same as they occur in `aList`),

```
val bListSet = bList.toSet

val result2 = for {
  i <- aList
  r <- if (i > 10) Some(i) else if (bListSet.contains(i)) Some(i*i) else None
} yield r

// result2: List[Int] = List(9, 25, 15, 20)
```

Or, you can take this approach which will be more efficient then both of the above and will also result in required ordering,

```
val bListSet = bList.toSet

val result3 = aList.flatMap({
  case i if i > 10 => Some(i)
  case i if bListSet.contains(i) => Some(i*i)
  case _ => None
})

// result3: List[Int] = List(15, 20, 9, 25)
```

Comment: I am mapping over `bList`, so the elment will be in `bList` .

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov fixed for the requirement.

Comment: Your final code doesn't return the result the comment says it does. It returns `List(9, 25, 15, 20) `

Comment: I suspect your first one can produce the squared ints in the wrong order (you convert to set for efficiency but that is not guaranteed to preserve order)

Answer (score 1):

My alternative for skinning the cat

```
val (x,y) = aList.partition( _ >10)
val r = x++(y intersect bList).map(e=>e*e)
// List(15, 20, 9, 25)
```